# add and delete multiple rows in a table based on user input

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa

so i have a table which has an auto increment primary key and 2 foreign keys each to a different tables primary key. so basically this table is used to store the relationship between table one and table 2 as shown bellow.

```
    this_table_id   table_one_id    table_two_id
    1                    1             2
    2                    1             1
    3                    2             1
```

the user can update all the entries grouped by table_one_id at the same time, so all the table_one_id=1 is shown to the user and he can remove or add table_one_id=1 relations to table 2 entries.

currently the solution i have implemented is, no matter what the user does update or not. when he submits i delete all the previous entries for that table_one_id and insert the values again. so if he updated them they get changed, if not its just wasted queries. average case scenario there at mostly 4 entries so not very intensive.

i imagine there should be a more elegant solution then deleting all the old values, the only thing i can think of would be checking for changes n then either doing an update or a delete or an insert for each entry based on what the user did but that feels tedious.

ps: using jsf front end and jpa backend

**Further clarification**

What i am looking for is the theory for when the user is shown multiple rows with the same value in a single column like table_one_id=1(so he would be shown rows 1 and 2 from the table above) and he deletes a few rows, adds new ones and presses submit

whats the best way to handle it programmatically. should i check each of his new entries and see if it is already in the table, if its not in the table add them, if they are in the table leave them and if the user removed something delete them or is there a better way. Is deleting all the old entries and inserting them fresh a reasonable solution

Comment: Post the query you are currently using.

Comment: @EternalHour like i said i am using jpa so they arent really normal sql queries but they translate, so for delete i am using DELETE FROM Houseservice h WHERE h.houseid=?1. for inset i am not using a query but basically its just looping through the values user entered and inserting them one at a time

Comment: Is it possibel to have duplicate  'table_one_id' and 'table_two_id' combination? for eg for row.  4                  1            2

Comment: @Rohit no it is not posible, i initally though about making a composite primary key using those values but this just seemed easier

Comment: Do you have any other column in this table other than these 3?

Comment: @Rohit, no these are the only 3 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try using triggers. Whenever an event of update would run, triggers can help you to fire queries before or after that event without having to go through the tedious job of updating again and again. You may refer to>>
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html for the syntax and usage.

Comment: i fail to see how triggers would help, please look at my new edit

Comment: I think you will have to find a way such that first everytime a user enters a value, it is compared to the previous entries. And apply conditional update command for that row such that only 'IF' that value is not found in the table already it gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

To configure a [Many-to-Many](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany) relationship you will require the mapping table but it does not require `this_table_id` column.

The mapping table is not separate entity in JPA hence does not require the ID column. see [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Example_of_a_ManyToMany_relationship_database)

Comment: the relationship between the two tables is many to many not onetomany